# How to enable tinymce on child window from parent

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm working on a web application that generates all HTML code from Java servlets and I need to generate HTML content that will popup another window with a tinymce frame. The problem seems to be in the tinymce's selector which doesen't recognize the elements in the child window. 
I've reduced my script to the following javascript code:

```
var childWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=600');
childWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body><textarea></textarea></body></html>');
var tinymceSRCScript = childWindow.document.createElement('script');
tinymceSRCScript.src = 'http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js';
childWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tinymceSRCScript);

function setTinymceOnChild() {
  if (!childWindow.tinymce) {
    setTimeout(setTinymceOnChild, 100);
  } else {
    childWindow.tinymce.init({selector:"textarea"}); 
    childWindow.alert('it went through')
  }
}

childWindow.addEventListener('load', setTinymceOnChild(), true);
```

I am opening the child window, I'm setting a basic HTML structure with a textarea inside and setting the tinymce public src. In the main window, I'm checking if the child window has initialized tinymce and then trying to set it to any `textarea` elements. Even if no error is prompted, the textarea inside the child window does not load.

I am limited to pure javascript(no JQuery) and IE 11.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script>
var childWindow = window.open('#', 'E-mail plugin', 'width=800, height=600');
childWindow.firstTime = true;
childWindow.document.write('<html><head>'
    + '</head><body><textarea></textarea>'
    + '<scr' 
    + 'ipt id="tinymcescript">'
    + '</scr' 
    + 'ipt>'
    + '<scr' 
    + 'ipt>var setTinymceOnChild = function(){if (!tinymce || !tinymce.init) {'
    + 'setTimeout(setTinymceOnChild, 100);}else{'
    + 'tinymce.init({selector:"textarea",'
    + 'height: 400,'
    + 'plugins: ['
    + '"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",'
    + '"searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",'
    + '"insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code"],'
    + 'toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"'
    +'});'
    + 'if(window.firstTime == true){window.location.reload();window.firstTime=false;}'
    + '}}; document.getElementById("tinymcescript").onload = function(){setTinymceOnChild();}; '
    + ' document.getElementById("tinymcescript").onerror=function(){alert("err")};'
    +'document.getElementById("tinymcescript").src="http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"; </scr' + 'ipt></body></html>');
</script>
```

The main points are:
- the code is part of the child window, so you don't need to pay attention to the child/parent references
- for some reason, it doesn't work on a first load. The tinymce didn't get displayed on load, but then it appeared on refreshing the popup. Therefore, I've added a refresh in the code
- the code looks pretty crappy and it would need to be better formatted in order to be maintainable
- the loading of the tinymce javascript is based on the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts

Comment: Indeed, the reload mechanism solved the issue, thanks!